# Why does this recursion code work like this?

Tags: java, recursion

I have been brainstorming this for 2 hours and I am on the brink of insanity. This is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RecursiveNestedLoops {
    public static int numberOfLoops;
    public static int numberOfIterations;
    public static int[] loops;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("N = ");
        numberOfLoops = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("K = ");
        numberOfIterations = input.nextInt();
        input.close();
        loops = new int[numberOfLoops];
        nestedLoops(0);
    }

    public static void nestedLoops(int currentLoop) {
        if (currentLoop == numberOfLoops) {
            printLoops();
            return;
        }

        for (int counter=1;counter<=numberOfIterations;counter++) {
            loops[currentLoop] = counter;
            nestedLoops(currentLoop + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void printLoops() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLoops; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d ", loops[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Now I have NO idea how but it works like it is supposed to. After 2 hours of thinking I got to the conclusion that I may not grasp what these lines do:

```
printLoops(); 
return;
```

printLoops(); - This calls the print method yeah.

return; - Shouldn't this end THE WHOLE nestedLoops method and just END the program? Instead what it does is it somehow restarts the method and it starts doing the rest of the for loop.

Comment: Where did you see that `return` ends a program?

Comment: Use a debugger to run the program step by step and inspect its [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)

Comment: @Pshemo It's at the start of a recursive method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it ends the method - which happens to be the last thing in the program.

Comment: ElliottFrisch and @Amadan you are right, I was a victim of bad indentation. Comment removed.

Comment: Define _last thing_.

Comment: @TsvetanDimitrov: The clue is in the name: `nestedLoops`. The function calls itself, creating layers of itself on the call stack. It's like Matryoshka dolls: each one says "open me, look at the next one, then close me"; but of course the one inside, when you inspect it, also says the same thing. It is only when you reach the smallest one and see the thing in the center that you can start closing them up.

Comment: @TsvetanDimitrov No, it's not (necessarily) the last thing in the program.  A `nestedLoops(10)` call will happily return control flow to where it was called from in a `nestedLoops(9)` call...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Last line in the main method is "nestedLoops(0);" - the nestedLoops getting called with a 0 for an argument. It got ended by the return statement.

Comment: So you're misunderstanding program execution and the _call stack_. That's what you should look into.

Comment: @TsvetanDimitrov: It did; but before that, it called `nestedLoops(1)`. And before *it* ended, it called `nestedLoops(2)`. etc, until they hit `println` in `nestedLoops(numberOfLoops)` and got returned before it could recurse into `nestedLoops(numberOfLoops + 1)`. And when `nestedLoops(2)` exited, it returned to `nestedLoops(1)`, which then returned to `nestedLoops(0)`, which returned to `main`; only then did the program end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> return; - Shouldn't this end THE WHOLE nestedLoops method and just END the program?

It will end the *current call* to `nestedLoops`. But `nestedLoops` is recursive — it calls itself — and ending the current call will not terminate all the calling code.

Consider this simple non-recursive example:

```
public void foo() {
    System.out.println("foo");
    return;
}

public void foobar() {
    foo();
    System.out.println("bar");
}
```

`foobar()` will print both `foo` and `bar`, because the `return` from the call to `foo()` does not terminate the call to `bar()`.

With recursion, it's the same thing, except that both calls are the same method. Terminating one call to `nestedLoops` does not terminate the other.

Answer (score 0):

When `currentLoop == numberOfLoops` it does stop, and `return`. Your first invocation, `currentLoop` is 0. Then 1. When `currentLoop` is `numberOfLoops` it stops. I believe your issue is recursing in the loop, I think you wanted

```
public static void nestedLoops(int currentLoop) {
    // System.out.printf("%d of %d%n", currentLoop, numberOfLoops);
    if (currentLoop == numberOfLoops) {
        printLoops();
        return;
    }
    for (int counter = 1; counter <= numberOfIterations; counter++) {
        loops[currentLoop] = counter;
    }
    nestedLoops(currentLoop + 1); // <-- HERE
}
```

Comment: It's not my code. I copied it from the book. They use this to show me what a recursion is. 2 hours of idiotically staring into it got me nowhere. Must be time to ditch the book or cut my veins or something.

Comment: @TsvetanDimitrov Let me define recursion for you; if you understand recursion stop reading this comment, otherwise go back to the start.

Comment: Ok I think I got it. It's something like a loop where the method calls itself and if I got this right the return; ends it when certain objective is met. What is that objective? I have no clear bars, limits, borders that I usually have with a for an example for loop.

Comment: The end condition is `if (currentLoop == numberOfLoops)`, which will return, thus preventing `nestedLoop` to be called again.